# How to redirect a user based on their referrer using React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'd like to redirect a user if he tries to access my website if his referrer isn't an accepted value.

I understand that I can do it with something like that :

```
if(url.referrer === 'www.example.com')
    REDIRECT
```

but it clearly isn't the safest method, so I was wondering if react offers a way kind of like this :

```
<Router>
  <Suspense fallback={<div/>}>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" referrer="www.example.com" component={example}/>
      <redirect referrer="*" to="www.example2.com/">
    </Switch>
  </Suspense>
</Router>
```

Also if the way of doing this could be switched to off in the development server it would be really amazing

Answer (score 1):

We have been searching with our team for exactly same solution some time ago, ended up checking document.referrer and then based on this redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, React-router does not provide what you want. You need to do it.

You can do a component like this:

```
function ReferrerRoute(props) {
  return function referrerRoute({ component: Component, redirectTo, referrer, ...rest }) {
    return (
      <Route {...rest} render={() => (document.referrer !== referrer ? <Component /> : <Redirect to={redirectTo} />)} />
    );
  };
}
```

Next you can do:

```
<Router>
  <Suspense fallback={<div/>}>
    <Switch>
      <ReferrerRoute redirectTo="www.example2.com" referrer="www.example.com" component={example}/>
    </Switch>
  </Suspense>
</Router>
```

Comment: Tip: for the referrer comparison I would recommend using a regular expression